# How to send scheduled message to Azure Service Bus with JMS

Tags: azure, amqp, azureservicebus, jmstemplate

Azure Service Bus has capability to send scheduled messages.
Sending scheduled messageses with AMQP protocol described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-request-response#message-operations

> Schedules messages.
> Request
>
> The request message must include the following application properties:
>
> | Key |     Value | Type |  Required |  Value Contents
>
> | operation |   string  | Yes   | com.microsoft:schedule-message
>
> | com.microsoft:server-timeout |    uint |  No |    Operation server timeout in milliseconds.|

I work with Azure Service Bus with java JmsTemplate from Spring Framework.
How map message headers to send scheduled message?

```
    @Test
public void sendMessageWithHeaders() {


    jmsTemplate.send("test-topic-2", new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage("test-123");
            ((JmsTextMessage) textMessage).setValidatePropertyNames(false);
            textMessage.setStringProperty("operation", "com.microsoft:schedule-message");

            textMessage.setIntProperty("com.microsoft:server-timeout", 100000);
            return textMessage;
        }
    });
}
```

-produce ordinal message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code work:

Azure SB use undocumented message annotation header `x-opt-scheduled-enqueue-time`

```
static final long ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS=60000;//millisecs

@Test
public void sendMessageWithHeaders() {


    jmsTemplate.send(queueName, new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage("test-123");
            ((JmsTextMessage) textMessage).setValidatePropertyNames(false);

            org.apache.qpid.proton.message.Message amqpMessage = ((AmqpJmsTextMessageFacade)((JmsTextMessage)textMessage).getFacade()).getAmqpMessage();
            HashMap applicationPropertiesMap = new HashMap();
            applicationPropertiesMap.put("operation", "com.microsoft:schedule-message");
            applicationPropertiesMap.put("com.microsoft:server-timeout", 100000000);
            amqpMessage.setApplicationProperties(new ApplicationProperties(applicationPropertiesMap));

            Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
            long t= date.getTimeInMillis();
            Date afterAddingTenMins=new Date(t + (10 * ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS));

            amqpMessage.getMessageAnnotations().getValue().put(Symbol.valueOf("x-opt-scheduled-enqueue-time"), afterAddingTenMins);

            return textMessage;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: .getAmqpMessage() is not available for AmqpJmsTextMessageFacade class for me. may be they removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Update 2021:
As you can see in my answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66975393/5273532), you need a slightly different approach, since `.getAmqpMessage()` is not available anymore:

```
public void sendDelayedMessage() {
    final var now = ZonedDateTime.now();
    jmsTemplate.send("test-queue", session -> {
        final var tenMinutesFromNow = now.plusMinutes(10);
        final var textMessage = session.createTextMessage("Hello Service Bus!");
        ((JmsTextMessage) textMessage).getFacade().setTracingAnnotation("x-opt-scheduled-enqueue-time", Date.from(tenMinutesFromNow.toInstant()));
        return textMessage;
    });
    log.info("Sent at: " + now);
}
```

Comment: FYI, Here is the documentation for the x-opt-scheduled-enqueue-time Message Annotation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide#message-annotations