# Schedule message for Azure Service Bus with JMS

Tags: java, azure, jms, azureservicebus, qpid

I want to send a scheduled message to the Azure Service Bus with JMS.
My code is based on `org.apache.qpid.jms.message.JmsMessage`. I've found one solution for the given problem, but it uses `org.apache.qpid.proton.message.Message` which has `.getMessageAnnotations()`, which allows to edit message annotations and add some properties that are correctly recognized and processed by Azure Service Bus. My message impl is missing that method.

What I've found in offical docs and implementations in node.js, to schedule a message with Azure Service Bus, you need to send header `BrokerProperties/brokerProperties` which has valid json.
Other headers/properties will be marked as `Customer properties` and ignored by Azure Service Bus.

[official azure docs about JMS](https://github.com/toddkitta/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-bus/service-bus-amqp-java.md) says that setting `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` is not officialy supported by JMS API. But it can be achieved manually by setting property.

So when I send message to the queue, then I can post process it in lambda and set some properties:

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, payload, message -> {
    var date = Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")).plus(delay, ChronoUnit.MILLIS).toInstant());
    var brokerProps = Map.of("ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc", date.toGMTString());
    message.setStringProperty(
        "brokerProperties",
        objectMapper.writeValueAsString(brokerProps)
    );
    return message;
});
```

And it doesn't work. The message arrives at the queue, but when I try to peek it on the Service Bus Explorer on Azure it throws error in the browser console and the operation lasts forever. I guess setting that property `brokerProperties` does some impact for Service Bus.
I have also tried to send a map with date as a string (with date format that is used by the Azure) like `"ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc", "Thu, 25 Mar 2021 12:54:00 GMT"`, but it also is recognized as an error by Service Bus (peeking lasts forever and error in the browser console is thrown).

I've tried to set string properties like `x-opt-scheduled-enqueue-time` or `x-ms-scheduled-enqueue-time` which I've found in other threads on SO, but none of them works with my example.

I saw that Microsoft gives some library for Java to communicate with Azure Service Bus, but I need to maintain independency from the Cloud provider in my code and don't include any additional libs.

Is there any example of using JMS message implementation from the package `org.apache.qpid.jms.message.JmsMessage` to set `BrokerProperties` for Azure Service Bus?

Comment: Added more info to clarify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My team is currently facing the same issue.

We found that the ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc property is set in the MessageAnnotationsMap. Unfortunately, the `org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.message.AmqpJmsMessageFacade`, which is used by JMS, has set the getter and setter to package private. But we found out that you can use the `setTracingAnnotation(String key, Object value)` Method.

Example:

```
public void sendDelayedMessage() {
    final var now = ZonedDateTime.now();
    jmsTemplate.send("test-queue", session -> {
        final var tenMinutesFromNow = now.plusMinutes(10);
        final var textMessage = session.createTextMessage("Hello Service Bus!");
        ((JmsTextMessage) textMessage).getFacade().setTracingAnnotation("x-opt-scheduled-enqueue-time", Date.from(tenMinutesFromNow.toInstant()));
        return textMessage;
    });
    log.info("Sent at: " + now);
}
```

Proof:
[image]

Big Thanks to my [teammate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4579026/christoph-giesche)!!